# Is there a way to add due date for Github like Gitlab

Tags: github, gitlab, github-issues

Is there a way to add due date for Github like Gitlab?
I know github has milestone but I want due date for each issues.
Do you have any recommended tools like Jira or Asana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there were any "due date" possible for an issue, you would see it exposed in the [GitHub API for issues](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/)

The only "`due_on`" field is on the associated milestone of an issue, not on the issue itself though.
So there is no direct "due date" for an issue.